# Use featured image from wordpress in css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am making a content page for my portfolio items on my website and I have set a space for the featured image of the post to slot into, however when ever I try and add it, it either does not show or just shows giant (original size).

How would I be able to make it appear in my background header image section?  Currently the grey fuzzy texture image - http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/portfolio/print/

I have managed to get the content from the post showing, the current images.

I have tried placing the following code in the `<section>` code area but I am yet to get anywhere near.  Any help would be great.  I am struggling to find anything online that works.

The code empty is:

```
<section id="banner">

</section>
```

What I have tried and failed with is:

```
<section id="banner">
<?php 
    global $post; 
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' ); 
?>
</section>
```

and also

```
<section id="banner">

<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>


</section>
```

Ideally I want to have the featured image replace this image code in the CSS;

```css
#banner {
  background-attachment: scroll,               fixed;
  background-color: #666;
  background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
  background-position: top left,               center center;
  background-repeat: repeat,                   no-repeat;
  background-size: auto,                       cover;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12em 0 20em 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: the_post_thumbnail(); has several arguments for size of image. check it out.

Comment: Hey.  I need to place it within the CSS though, adding it into the page code just pushes everything out.. I want to replace this section of css basically with the featured image;

#banner {
  background-attachment: scroll,       fixed;
  background-color: #666;
  background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
  background-position: top left,      center center;
  background-repeat: repeat,       no-repeat;
  background-size: auto,       cover;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12em 0 20em 0;
  text-align: center;
 }

Comment: You need to write image location outside of css ( i mean: <section id="banner" style="... thumbnail()...">, because php doesn't exists at your css file.

Comment: How can I make the image fit within the frame though without using css?

I am completely lost on how to make it show within the frame

Comment: If your image sizes are dynamic, you can't, or atleast it's so hard, otherwise, you have to define your own image thumbnail sizes. Check this out: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: Add a placeholder to your `#banner` css if you want and place the image src to the dom 
ex. `<div id="banner" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $src[0];?>);"></div>`